# codeigniter encrypt returning wrong on new server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encryption

I have a database on an old linux server that holds my clients login information. Username and password, encrypted with CodeIgniter encrypt library. I am in the middle of changing server to a new linux server. I have transferred the site and the database to the new server. The site takes the entered username and password, pulls the password from the database on the new server, decrypts the password and compares it to the entered one. The problem is that on the new server the returned value is totally different and includes lots of special characters so the passwords never match! I thought it was the charset of the new database, as it was set to UTF8 and my old database is latin1, but I've changed this and it's exactly the same. The site is identical on both servers, so the encryption key is the same. I'm totally baffled.

The value returned from the database before decryption is correct.

I know this is not the best way to do authentication and I plan to change it, but please don't take this question as a chance to tell me how bad this way of doing things is... I just need to get it to work please :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a server configuration issue.

Does the new server have `Mcrypt` support/enabled?

You could try run `$this->encrypt->encode_from_legacy` before decoding to see if you have a compatibility problem.

**update:**

Codeigniter will use **mcrypt** for encoding/decoding.  If this extension is not enabled, it will use **xor**

This could be your issue.  Ask your hosting provider about enabling the required(check source file) php extensions

Comment: I shall try that now. Thank you.

Comment: I get an error: `A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice  Message: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_MODE_ECB - assumed 'MCRYPT_MODE_ECB'  Filename: libraries/Encrypt.php
Line Number: 188`

Comment: Does this mean the new server doesn't have Mcrypt support/enabled?

Comment: It would seem so Yes. Check your error logs **application/logs/** You may have some extensions disabled, hence the decoding mismatch.

Comment: I don't have a log file for today... that's odd isn't it?! The directory permissions are 755

Comment: You may have error logging disabled. Contact your hosting provider about the extensions.You may have to check the source code to see what other extensions are required. It may fix your issue.

Comment: I have sent them an email. Thank you for your help. I have error logging set to 1 int he config file as I always do. It's bothering me that it's not logging. I shall report back as to what my server people have to say.